# XSLT : Grouping or Braking from Loop

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach, key

My problem in xslt is like this . I have a xml that looks like

```
  <data>
   <Record>
        <key>1</key>
         <idType>Atype</idType>
         <idValue>AValue</idValue> 
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <key>1</key>
     <idType>Btype</idType>
     <idValue>BValue</idValue> 
   </Record>
   <Record>
     <key>2</key>
     <idType>Atype</idType>
     <idValue>AValue</idValue> 
   </Record>
   <Record>
<key>3</key>
<idType>Atype</idType>
 <idValue>AValue</idValue> 
 </Record>
<Record>
 <key>3</key>
 <idType>Btype</idType>
 <idValue>BValue</idValue> 
</Record>
<Record>
<key>3</key>
<idType>Ctype</idType>
<idValue>CValue</idValue> 
</Record>
<Record>
<key>4</key>
</Record>
</data>
```

and should be transformed to :

```
 <data>
<Record>
    <key>1</key>
    <ids>
        <idType>Atype</idType>
        <idValue>AValue</idValue>
        <idType>Btype</idType>
        <idValue>BValue</idValue>
    </ids>
</Record>
<Record>
    <key>2</key>
    <ids>
        <idType>Atype</idType>
        <idValue>AValue</idValue>
    </ids>
</Record>
<Record>
    <key>3</key>
    <idType>Atype</idType>
    <idValue>AValue</idValue>
    <idType>Btype</idType>
    <idValue>BValue</idValue>
    <idType>Ctype</idType>
    <idValue>CValue</idValue>
</Record>
<Record>
    <key>4</key>
</Record>
 </data>
```

Each record with a particular `<key>` can have a `<idType>` and its `<idValue>` with possibility of NO `<idType>` and its `<idValue>`. I need to merge all records with same `<key>` into one and add combine their `<idType>` and `<idValue`> as shown above .

Assuming that I can get the document sorted by `<Key>` , I have tried the for each loop but find it hard to skip the loop if I have a matching `<Key>` in next record . Can xslt Key function help me here ?

Please advise . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

It is a grouping problem, with XSLT 2.0 you can use `for-each-group`, e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="data">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Record" group-by="key">
     <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="key"/>
      <ids>
        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/(* except key)"/>
      </ids>
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

with XSLT 1.0 use [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml)

```
<xsl:key name="group" match="Record" use="key"/>
<xsl:template match="data">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each select="Record[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', key)[1])]">
     <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="key"/>
      <ids>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('group', key)/*[not(self::key)]"/>
      </ids>
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```